# IBM Websphere 9 Second server

Tags: websphere

I have IBM Websphere running with the default server1. 
I wanted to try and add another server (called server2), where I will install the same application as in server1, however it will have different connections (different database, different ActiveMQ connections).

I have reached to the point where i need to start the application, however I am getting the following error:

```
Test application is deployed to the server2 server. Stop or start the application from a console running on that server.
```

If i Try to go to the IBM admin console running on port 9044, i get the following error:

```
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ibm/console/login.do has not been defined.

SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle localhost:9044 has not been defined.
```

I tried to look for solution however i cannot find anything. I created the second server using the wsadmin command.

Thank you

Comment: Did you change the port when create second server?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes, the port is changed to 9044, and added to the virtual host. If i try in the url 9045 for example i get nothing (no error) as the port is not added.